# MatFormField outline issue

Tags: angular-material

When I change the font type in my form, label overlays the outline. 
How can i fix this?

[image]

in the following image it is shown how it should be:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question seems too broad. What have you tried? What is your code? Please check out [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and edit your question to include a reproducible example.

Comment: Also possible duplicate of [How do you keep parents of floated elements from collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing?rq=1) and [floating label and placeholder overlapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53894005/floating-label-and-placeholder-overlapping)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you keep parents of floated elements from collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like after 3 years there's still no fix to this issue in Angular Material.

However, there are two workarounds:

**First workaround**:

- create a directive that links to all `mat-form-field` components (directives) with `appearance` attribute set to `outline`
- listen to `document.fonts.ready` event and run `updateOutlineGap` on the `MatFormField`
- export the directive in `AppModule` or `SharedModule` to make it accessible everywhere
- this way Angular will update the outline size as soon as the custom font is loaded

```
import { AfterViewInit, Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { MatFormField } from '@angular/material/form-field';

@Directive({
    selector: 'mat-form-field[appearance=outline]',
})
export class UpdateOutlineGapDirective implements AfterViewInit {
    constructor(private formField: MatFormField) {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        document.fonts.ready.then(() => {
            this.formField.updateOutlineGap();
        });
    }
}
```

**Second workaround**:

- add `#userNameField` to your `mat-form-field` element
- add `(focus)="userNameField.updateOutlineGap()"` to the input element
- this way every time the input is focused, Angular will update the outline size